# Iptables forward all internal traffic

Tags: linux, openvpn, iptables

I have a VM with an internal interface connected to local LAN. The VM has a working OpenVPN connection to another site. How do I forward all incoming traffic on the local interface through the VPN tunnel with iptables? I’m running an Ubuntu distro.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to do a site-to-site VPN with the existing connection, you need to have routing paths via the VPN. Let's say that you're in Site #1 (all things are symmetric, regardless of which is acting as OpenVPN server).

1. First, you need to be sure that the VM with the VPN connection (that we can call "VPN#1") can reach the remote subnet. This is done by adding a route using OpenVPN configuration

   - If "VPN#1" is the OpenVPN client, you can either add it in the server using `push` keyword, or add it locally using `route`
   - If "VPN#1" is the OpenVPN server, you can add it using `route`, or using an external tool like `ip`
2. Then, you need to be sure that both the "VPN#1" and the remote endpoint has the IP forwarding enabled (add `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` to `/etc/sysctl.conf` and reload using `sysctl -p`)
3. If VPN#1 is the default gateway, then it's done. If it's not, you need either add a static route for the remote LAN in the default gateway, or you can add a static route on each host of your LAN.
4. Check the firewall in VPN#1: it should be configured to allow traffic between LAN and VPN interfaces (see `FORWARD` chain in `filter` table using `iptables`)

If you repeat this on the remote side, everything should work. Use `ping` and `traceroute` to debug any issue.

Comment: I want to forward all ip traffic to the site local lan through the vpn connection. My local lan is at 10.11.0.0/16. The remote one is at 192.168.2.0/24

Comment: So you want to be able to reach the remote LAN from the local LAN?

Comment: Yes that’s what I want

Comment: I edited your original question (edits are in pending) to specify that you want a site-to-site VPN

Answer (score 0):

OK got it working now. I can RDP the server on the other side from my local LAN. I cannot use smb to access the administrative shares on the windows servers on the other side. This are the IP table rules i used:

/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o ens160 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i ens160 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT